# jaspersoft studio eclipse plugin download error

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jaspersoft-studio

when i'm trying to install jaspersoft studio into eclipse using [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=31S3BxPUzjI)  and this error came up.

**eclipse version - Eclipse Kepler (4.3.2) 

OS - Ubuntu 15.10**

[image]